# Move or regenerate Azure microsoft.web/certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, certificate

I need to reorganize my Azure resource groups and could move everything except the `microsoft.web/certificates`. When I try to move this you get a validation error

> Resource move is not supported for resource types 'Microsoft.Web/certificates'. (Code: ResourceMoveNotSupported, Target: /subscriptions/{GUID}/resourceGroups/{Old Group Name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/{Name})

Anybody knows how to move these certificates or how I can regenerate/replace this certificate?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you’re attempting to move resources to a different/new Resource Group (RG).
There are some limitations and checklist/guidelines for moving resources.

Checkout this doc: [Move App Service resources to a new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations).

Also, note that Azure resource type `Microsoft.web/certificates` do not support move operation between RGs, but only supports move operations across subscriptions.

Reference: [move-support-resources#microsoftweb](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftweb)

You may want to validate:  For your Azure web app, select `Diagnose and solve problems`. Then, select `Configuration and Management` >> Select `Migration Options`.

[image: App Service - Certificate]

Comment: Yes I already found this out. Eventually I fixed it by regenerating new certificates for the app services and deleting the old ones.